# Show image from S3 in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router

I'm currently trying to show an image from my S3 bucket using the following code:

```
<img src={Post.data} alt={Post.text}></img>
```

Where Post.data is the link to the object in the bucket, and Post.text is alt text.

However, when the React application is built, the src attribute and its data are missing from the tag:

Ex:

```
<img alt="Alt text"></img>
```

How would I show images from my S3 bucket and why is it removing the src attribute?

Comment: Check if your `Post.data` is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Post.data is from the useState hook, I wasn't properly setting state so the property was undefined.